# jvector map set color for selected region on region click

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I used jvector map

```
var colorData = {
 "1" : "#fcadb2", 
 "2" : "#0071A4",
 "3" : "#C8EEFF", 
 "4" : "#0071A4",
 "5" : "#C8EEFF", 
 "6" : "#0071A4"
```

}

```
$.getJSON ("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/map_data.php?id="+id+"",{},function(mapa){
    var dataC = eval(mapa);
    var countryData = []; 
    //for each country, set the code and value
    $.each(dataC.countries, function() {
        countryData[this.ccode] = this.visits;
    });
    //World map by jvectormap
    $('#world-map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill',
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#e4e4e4',
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: 'none',
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
            }
        },
        series: {
            regions: [{
                    values: countryData,
                    scale: colorData, //['#3E5E6B', '#A6BAC2'],
                    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                }]
        },
        onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
            //alert(code);
            // highlight the countries
            highlight_lang(code);
        }
    });


});



    function highlight_lang(code) {

    var map = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
    map.clearSelectedRegions();
    //clear the array values
    map.series.regions[0].clear();
    map.setSelectedRegions([code]);

}
```

On region click i called the function `highlight_lang`. By using this other than the selected regions are cleared. by default the yellow color is filled while click on the region. How to change the color of the selected region.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

In the regionStyle property add the **selected** property as follows:

```
regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill: '#e4e4e4',
                "fill-opacity": 1,
                stroke: 'none',
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "stroke-opacity": 1
            },
            selected:{
                 fill: "#2A3F52"
}

        },
```

Please let me know if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved as follows:

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    regionsSelectable: true, // <------------ HERE
    regionsSelectableOne: true, // <------------ HERE
    regionStyle: {
        selected: { // <------------ HERE
            fill: 'yellow'
        },
        selectedHover: {}
    },
});
```